# Angular Service Worker crashes in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, service-worker

Angular Service Worker has problems in Safari

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open https://angular.io in Safari
2. Turn on Developer Menu in Safari
3. Click Develop > Empty Caches to Clear Caches
4. Refresh page and you will see Error which is shown in picture

Is there any solutions that can resolve this issue

Comment: Yes, if we close the safari browser and open again. it started working. Seems like some issue on safari.

Comment: Angular guys updated files in 7.0; They were thinking issue was caused because cache is sometimes blocked, and Service Worker wasn't able to write cache. But seems like it wasn't the case

Comment: Please raise an issue in github

Comment: I've already raised, I was just wondering if someone has found solution for this